# AJAX call returns either an ARRAY or a single OBJECT causing an error

Tags: javascript, ajax

Javascript is really not my strength, in fact I'm terrible at it, so have just started to get to grips with it.

I have an AJAX call to an API using GET. The API returns standard JSON.

If I don't supply an ID, my response is ALL records. If I supply an ID, I receive a SINGLE record response. This is correct.

Here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: apiURL,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "Get",
      success: function (data) {
        var row;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          row = row + "<tr>";
          row = row + "<td>" + data[i].id + "</td>";
          row = row + "<td>" + data[i].latitude + "</td>";
          row = row + "<td>" + data[i].longitude + "</td>";
          row = row + "<td>" + data[i].description + "</td>";
          row = row + "<td>" + data[i].dateRecorded + "</td>";
          row = row + "</tr>";
        };
        $("#results").append(row);
        ......
```

As you can see I then want to take the results and stick them in a table. This works well when my response is multiple records, but if my response is a single record, I get an OBJECT rather than an ARRAY and the code fails at `data.length`. Why don't I get an ARRAY with a single element and what can I do about it??

I would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Well, that means your API is returning JSON that is structured like an `Object`. If you provide us with what that object looks like, we can maybe help you.

Comment: Well that's apparently the way that API works. In fact, in your own question you wrote, "If I supply an ID, I receive a SINGLE record response. This is correct."  If that's correct, then what's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
success: function (data) {

    if( !data.length ) data = [ data ];

    ...

}
```

This will check if the returned value is a single object or not. If it's a good API it would always return an array, but since it's not you are going to have to check yourself.

And yes, there are better ways to check if the data is an array, like `@Quentin`'s answer with

```
!(data instanceof Array)
```

Comment: This isn't a good test to see if something is an array. It will fail if the API returns an array of `0` length or if it return an object with a truthy `length` property.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, true, but it will do in a pinch.

Answer (score 5):

> Why don't I get an ARRAY with a single element

Because that is the design decision the authors of the API you are using made.

> and what can I do about it??

Test to see what you get. Put it in an array if it isn't one already.

```
if (! (data instanceof Array) ) {
    data = [data];
}
```

Comment: Thank you to both @somethinghere and @Quentin! both solutions work perfectly. I have to choose one as an answer so first past the post. Many thanks to all once again

Comment: Why not use `Array.isArray(data)`?